# OpenGL (LWJGL) GL_QUADS behaves oddly

Tags: java, performance, swing, opengl, lwjgl

I know all this stuff with `glBegin` \ `glEnd` is deprecated for years, but I was just experimenting and found strange behaviour of `GL_QUAD` rendering mode.

I am making a map editor with LWJGL + Swing. So I am rendering the whole (at once) map of **256x256** tiles. I know it is wrong, but it is just a test.

As you know, the fewer draw calls you make, the better. So according to the logic if I do something like this:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
for (x = 0 to.. xSize)
   for (y = 0 to.. ySize)
       world.getTile(x, y).render();
glEnd();
```

It will be much faster than:

```
for (x = 0 to.. xSize)
   for (y = 0 to.. ySize) {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    world.getTile(x, y).render();
    glEnd();
}
```

But the practise shows the opposite.
Here are the screens.

1st way (1 drawCall):

[image]

2nd way (many drawCalls):

[image]

if you'd like to see the actual code for rendering there it is:

1)

```
if (needsRecompile) {
    needsRecompile = false;
    glNewList(terrainList, GL_COMPILE);
    GRenderEngine.startDrawingQuads();
    for (int i = 0; i < world.xSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < world.ySize; j++) {
            Tile t = world.getTile(i, j);
            t.renderTile(world, i, j);
        }
    }
    GRenderEngine.stopDrawing();
    glEndList();
}
```

2)

```
if (needsRecompile) {
    needsRecompile = false;
    glNewList(terrainList, GL_COMPILE);
    for (int i = 0; i < world.xSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < world.ySize; j++) {
            GRenderEngine.startDrawingQuads();
            Tile t = world.getTile(i, j);
            t.renderTile(world, i, j);
            GRenderEngine.stopDrawing();
        }
    }
    glEndList();
}
```

What is wrong with this or I do not understand something well?

**EDIT:**
Just made another test:

```
if (needsRecompile) {
    needsRecompile = false;
    glNewList(terrainList, GL_COMPILE);
    int sectors = 2;
    for (int k = 0; k < sectors; k++) {
        GRenderEngine.startDrawingTriangles();
        for (int i = world.xSize/sectors*k; i < world.xSize/sectors*(k+1); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < world.ySize; j++) {
                Tile t = world.getTile(i, j);
                t.renderTile(world, i, j);
            }
        }
        GRenderEngine.stopDrawing();
    }
    glEndList();
}
```

Now it gives almost 0% CPU usage, the best perfomance. And I adapted the tiles to render via triangles.

Comment: Your test methodology does not seem very scientific, the two screenshots are not even from the same part of your level editor.

Comment: @Andon they are the same, just in the second screen I placed grass there. But the coords are the same. Anyway, this doesn't matter at all. I am rendering the whole map at once, even offscreen tiles.

Comment: By the way. Just changed rendering mode to GL_TRIANGLES. Now if I render them like in second way it gives almost the same perfomance. This relates to the first way too. But I discovered that if I place glBegin/glEnd in the body of X-loop (what makes 256 drawCalls - one for each column) it gives me MUCH BETTER perfomance. So if I render one tile per drawCall, it gives good perfomance. If I render all tiles per drawCall it is the worst perfomance. And if I render one column of tiles per drawCall it is the best perfomance.

Comment: It seems that if I draw more than N triangles (N is about ~160/320k) per one drawCall perfomance drops pretty bad. And if I draw less or N triangles per drawCall it gives me 0% CPU usage.

Comment: If you want to do performance testing, the simplest means is to use `System.nanoTime()` before and after the code you are trying to test, and take the delta of that. Then average this over a period of time to get an indication of execution time. Task manager is *never* a performance measure. It is at most an indicator.

Comment: @Bartvbl my eyes are not perfomance meausure too? FPS drops almost to zero in that case.

Comment: @Oldestkon That is only an indication. The actual cause of the FPS drop can be many different things. It doesn't *prove* that the code you are talking about is the actual cause of it. Unless you know for sure what causes the drop optimising the drawing code won't help you. So you should really try to do performance testing using measured nano times rather than your own observations.